# Dynamically create hashes within arrays within arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, hash

I'm working on creating an array of:
hashes for all words
within all paragraph-arrays
for an array of all files in a folder

I believe I have got the hashes for all words, within an array of all paragraphs. But to do this for every file, and create a specific key for every file, is a bridge too far.

This is my code so far. It goes wrong at creating a unique array for all files in a folder, and get ALL paragraph arrays of that file into the files array.

```
numberfiles = Dir.glob(File.join('**', '*')).select { |file| File.file?(file) }.count
    countfiles+1
    # HERE I MAKE THE ARRAY FOR ALL FILES
        filesArray = Array.new(numberfiles.to_i, Hash.new)
        for j in 0...numberfiles.to_i do
            filesArray[j] = Hash.new    
        end

#now to open all textfiles..
Dir.glob("*.txt").each do |textfile|


    lines = File.readlines(textfile)
    text = lines.join
    paragraph_count = text.split("\.\r").length
    #create array with key for every paragraph
    testArray = Array.new(paragraph_count.to_i, Hash.new)
    for $i in 0...paragraph_count.to_i do
        testArray[$i] = Hash.new    
    end
    words_in_each_paragraph = Array.new

    i = 0
```

Here i want to save all the testarrays into the filearray. And that isn't working:

```
File.foreach(textfile, "\.\r") do |paragraph|
    word_hash = {}
    paragraph.split(/\W+/).each_with_object(word_hash) { |w, h|
        h[w] = []
    }
    words_in_each_paragraph << word_hash
    testArray[i][:value] = word_hash
    filesArray[j][:file] = testArray # HERE IT GOES WRONG
    i += 1
end

puts filesArray[1]
end
```

Comment: Why are you pasting all the code.. Only give the pain areas..

Comment: Why are you using `for` loops? Use an `each`

Comment: Arup, I'm pasting most of the code so to get the context clear: it is a dynamically created hash within a dynamically created array within a [currently-not-working-and-not-dynamic] array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do but I know that you don't really have to preallocate the size of arrays in Ruby. The following code goes through each .txt-file, splits them into paragraphs and places each of the words of those paragraphs in a hash. That word hash is appended to the paragraphs array which in turn is appended to the files array.

```
files = []

Dir.glob("*.txt").each do |textfile|
  paragraphs = []
  File.foreach(textfile, "\n\n") do |paragraph|
    words = Hash.new(0)
    paragraph.split(/\W+/).each {|word| words[word] += 1}
    paragraphs << words
  end
  files << paragraphs
end

p files
```

Answer (score 2):

When you want to do something with each element of something enumerable and store the result in an array, then think `map`.

```
result = Dir.glob("*.txt").map do |textfile|
  File.read(textfile).split("\n\n").map do |paragraph| #again!
    words = Hash.new(0)
    paragraph.split(/\W+/).each {|word| words[word] += 1} #copied from @Jonas Elfström
  end
end
p result
```

Comment: That is the way to go. Now I want to change my answer. :)

Comment: @JonasElfströmsteenslag and steenslag: awesome work. This is what I need (and i have to admit: going from 50 lines to 7 is pure beauty). 
Now, how is everything mapped/indexed after this? What would the reference be to the second paragraph of the second file? / how would i reference all paragraphs of all files in a loop?

Comment: `files[1][1]` contains the second paragraph of the second file. If you want to loop over all paragraphs just files.flatten first. Also consider if using `map` is more appropriate.